# How can I change a Bootstrap Toggle with a dynamically value?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, toggle

I'm doing an update action where the user click over an element in a table and then change the value by switching a [bootstrap toggle](https://www.bootstraptoggle.com/), but I don't know how and where should I do the change.

This is my code:

First, the user can click over the element, sending the Id:

```
<div class="btn fa-hover col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" data-toggle="modal" onclick='wordEditModal({{key.id}})' data-target="#wordUpdateModal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
```

Then, it calls to `wordEditModal` function, to make a request to the django endpoint:

```
url:'/socialanalyzer/dictionary_edit_modal/',
```

It returns the polarity of the word clicked and simultaneously in the HTML, a modal is opened, here I should display the value returned with the bootstrap toggle:

```
<form method="get" novalidate>
{% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Now, this bootstrap toggle always display Positive value, I want that it display dynamically from the endpoint the value-->
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="polaridad">Polarity:</label>
            <input id="toggle-polarity" checked type="checkbox" data-on="Positive" data-off="Negative" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="100">
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick='wordUpdate()' value="Guardar" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is my ajax function:

```
function wordEditModal(wordId) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/socialanalyzer/dictionary_edit_modal/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
          word_id: wordId
     },success: function(data) {

        if (data.data.code==200) {

            // This is what I tried, but didn't work
            if (data.data.polarity.toLowerCase() == 'p'){
                $('#toggle-polarity').bootstrapToggle('Positive')
            }else {
                $('#toggle-polarity').bootstrapToggle('Negative')
            }
        }else{
            console.log('Error to load modal',data);
          }
        }
    })
}
```

My question is, How can I dynamycally change the value of the bootstrap toggle, according to the value that returns the endpoint?

**Positive** and **Negative** are the possible values, so if the user clicked over a word with Negative polarity, when the modal is opened, the bootstrap toggle must be display Negative (danger) option, if the word is Positive then the bootstrap toggle must be display Positive (success) option.

I tried also with something like this in the Ajax function, but didn't work:

```
if (data.data.polarity.toLowerCase() == 'p'){
    $("#toggle-polarity").val("success")
}else {
    $("#toggle-polarity").val("danger")
}
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Can you do some basic debugging and `console.log(data)` as first statement in your `success: function(data) {`? Also, did you check the console for error? My guess is that `data.data.code` doesn't exist in the first place.

Comment: Sure, the endpoint response in json format: ```console.log(data)``` show this: ```{code: 200, polarity: "N", id: 6, word: "anyWord"}``` so the polarity value is: ```console.log(data.data.polarity)```

Comment: No, it's `data.polarity`

Comment: This condition in the Ajax works: ```(data.data.polarity.toLowerCase() == 'p')``` but the bootstrap toggle is open always with Positive value, I know that in the html I have ```data-on="Positive" data-off="Negative"``` but If I skip that part, the bootstrap toggle show "On" or "Off"

Comment: Try calling `.bootstrapToggle("on")` and `.bootstrapToggle("off")` instead: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/zup6yts7/

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion of @Chris G this was my solution:

```
function wordEditModal(wordId) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/socialanalyzer/dictionary_edit_modal/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
          word_id: wordId
     },success: function(data) {
        if (data.data.code==200) {
            //console.log($('#toggle-polarity').bootstrapToggle()[0]['value'])
            if (data.data.polarity.toLowerCase() == 'p'){
                $('#toggle-polarity').bootstrapToggle('on')
                //console.log('Is positive')
            }else {
                $('#toggle-polarity').bootstrapToggle('off')
                //console.log('Is negative')                
            }

        }else{
            console.log('Error to load modal',data);
          }
        }
    })
}
```

I hope this will be useful for anyone else.

Comment: Hi Manuel, feel free to heavily edit your question by removing all the irrelevant parts. This is only about changing a bootstrap toggle plugin input programmatically, everything else should be removed. Most importantly, fix the title and tags.